# Setting up Android Development Tools in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**If you download android SDK now, it comes with a custom eclipse with android fully installed on it, so way easier**

***Solved!, it was solved by downloading Eclipse Indigo, but as indicated online, they tell you to go to `‘File>New>Other…>Android>Android Project‘`, but Android Project is not in the list?***

So,

I recently wanted to start making a Java android app, and by going to developer.android.com, they told me, install Android SDK tools, so i did that, then in eclipse, i have to got to help, ad new software, and use this : `Enter Android Development Tools in the Name field, and https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ in the Location field.` , so i did that, and it keeps giving me this error :

```
(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found
```

i looked it up on google, but couldnt find anything...
Does anyone now how to fix this?

Greets

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Hi, i use eclipse they told me to use, eclipse IDE for Java developpers, or Eclipse Galileo

Comment: which os you are using win/linux? becoz enev I have faced many errors during installing ADT in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Eclipse Helios. Download **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2) & update it latest packages by goto to menu *Help -> Check for new updates*.

Download & install Android SDK.

**To install ADT Plugin:**

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
   Click Add, in the top-right corner.
2. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. Click OK
   Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
4. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
5. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
6. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
   Note: If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
7. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance this morning. I just found your stack Overflow contribution worked exactly right the first time I tried it. I have two questions for you: 1. If I start another Android java activity from another activity, what possible reasons might exist  for why I cannot launch another activity 2. How do I decode a QR Barcode from a Android Samsung Galaxy Java camera picture? Thank you very much. Frankc

Answer (score 1):

Procedure to work with android in Eclipse juno is :

`Step 1:` Install jdk-7 version and then Install `installer_r16-windows.exe`

`Step 2:` now unzip the android-sdk and paste it into disk c android folder and replace all.

`Step 3:` now unzip the eclipse-juno.

`Step 4:` open eclipse ide and go to the help option and click on new software install option.

`Step 5:` click on archive and give the path to ur ADT-20.0.3 or any version and choose restart eclipse option.

`Step 6:` now two green button will be displayed on the left most upper side of eclipse.

`Step 7:` first click on small arrow type button and see all the packages are installed if not choose install package.

`Step 8:` now click on second big green button named AVD i.e android virtual device.

`Step 9:` click on new and configure ram and all u want in your AVD.

`Step 10:` your AVD is on screen now.

Answer (score 0):

(Using the comments to provide an answer)

Try using the latest version of Eclipse (Juno), or at least Eclipse Indigo.  The newer version of the Android Framework might have dependencies that the latest versions of Eclipse provide.

If this is incorrect / doesn't work, let us know so we can update the solution.

Comment: I'd try it anyway, I know a lot of people that still develop in Juno for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install ADT plugins yet or something goes wrong.

Download ADT-20 form [HERE](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview)

**In eclipse goto--> Help --> Install new Software --> Select ADT-20.zip**

For step-by-step instruction [HOW TO INSTALL ANDROID](http://developer-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-install-android-step-by-step.html) see this

Comment: It says "Page not found" for the ADT zip.

Comment: Yes, i got the' page not found' to

Answer (score 0):

As per your given error it is sure an  version problem.. you might be trying to add ADT whose version is below ADT-20 and your ecllips is asking for ADT-20..so try to provide link which contains ADT version 20. If still problem exists go to : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html there they have also given download for ADT-20.zip file download it and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I installed [Eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2) and it worked perfect... because it's version 3.7.2 so it should be working fine with this.