# Android project not showing up in eclipse -> new menu

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to set up android for eclipse.I have followed all the instructions [Setting up Android Development Tools in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877077/setting-up-android-development-tools-in-eclipse).

I even installed SDK tools from https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

I have even looked for updates in eclipse and updated them.

But still i cant see the "android project" in the "new" menu.(I have looked in "others" too).

Can anyone please help me.

I am using eclipse juno.

Comment: You are using the Eclipse that comes with the SDK right?

Comment: Just go to File->New->Project.  What do you see when the dialog opens?

Comment: @user1282637 How can i get to know that?

Comment: @DanielNugent I see options like general,java,csv etc.There is no android project option in that

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877077/setting-up-android-development-tools-in-eclipse/11877626#11877626

Comment: @hello id your Eclipse icon the Eclipse logo or the Android logo like this: http://i.imgur.com/ZjbeQsM.png

Comment: @user1282637 No.It is not.What should i do now?

Comment: @hello did you have Eclipse installed before you installed the SDK? The SKD folder has Eclipse in it specifically for Android...it is in the Eclipse folder of the Android SDK root folder: http://i.imgur.com/SbIFYom.png

Comment: @user1282637 Yes i have installed eclipse before i installed sdk.And I do not have an adt-bundle folder inside android sdk!

Comment: @hello post a screenshot of what your Android SDK folder/content looks like